# How can I check the pdf formula of function rged in r programming？

Tags: r, statistics, fgarch

I am using the built in function in R, rged to generate ged data. but how can i know what pdf formula are used in it and also the default mean and variance in general?

Tried to check on the fgarch package rdocumentation, but did not find anything related.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.